# how to display collection of objects in an html table with irregular headers using c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table

I copied a code from this [site](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/tables/irregular/) which discusses how to create an html table with irregular headers.

```
<table>
  <col>
  <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
  <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Mars</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Venus</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Produced</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
    <th scope="col">Produced</th>
    <th scope="col">Sold</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Teddy Bears</th>
    <td>50,000</td>
    <td>30,000</td>
    <td>100,000</td>
    <td>80,000</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">Board Games</th>
    <td>10,000</td>
    <td>5,000</td>
    <td>12,000</td>
    <td>9,000</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have a method that retrieves a collection of Departments  with collection of Subgroups, but I dont know hot to display the collection into the html using c#. I dont even know where to begin.

here is my department class

```
public class Department : CreateDetail
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<string> ListSubGroups { get; set; }
    public List<SubGroup> SubGroupees { get; set; }

    public Department()
    {
        DepartmentId = 0;
        Name = "";
        Description = "";
        ListSubGroups = new List<string>();
        SubGroupees = new List<SubGroup>();
    }

}

//method to retrieve the list of Departments

public List<Department> RetrieveMany(Department entity)
{
    var command = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "RetrieveDepartments", CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentId", entity.DepartmentId).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", entity.Name).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;


    DataTable dt = SqlHelper.GetData(command);
    var items = new List<Department>();

    if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0) return items;
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var item = new Department();

        item.DepartmentId = row["DepartmentId"].GetInt();
        item.Name = row["Name"].GetString();
        item.Description = row["Description"].GetString();                
        item.SubGroupees = SubGroupees(item.DepartmentId);  //retrieves a list of subgroups per department


        items.Add(item);
    }

    return items;
}

//method to retrieve SubGroups based on Department Id
public List<SubGroup> SubGroupees(int departmentId)
{
    var command = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "RetrieveSubGroups", CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SubGroupId", 0).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentId", departmentId).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;

    DataTable dt = SqlHelper.GetData(command);
    var items = new List<SubGroup>();

    if (dt.Rows.Count <= 0) return items;

    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        var item = new SubGroup();

        item.DepartmentId = departmentId;
        item.SubGroupId = row["SubGroupId"].GetInt();
        item.Name = row["Name"].GetString();    


        items.Add(item);
    }

    return items;
}
```

Comment: are you able to manually write the desired html code?

Comment: is this asp.net Forms or MVC? The implementation would be somewhat different depending on the framework